# How use DMM thermocouple probe hands-free to monitor heatsink temperature?

Tags: measurement, temperature, multimeter, heatsink, probe

I suppose this is more of a lab practice question than electronics per se, but I wonder if there's a standard-ish way to **mount the K-type thermocouple that comes with my Fluke DMM** so I can monitor the temperature of a power transistor and/or heatsink over time, hands-free?

I'm certainly open to a special-purpose thermocouple or other sensor that could be screwed or perhaps preferably clamped in place so I could follow the temperature changes without having to poke the little temperature probe tip in there each time I want to take a reading and wait the minute or so it takes to stabilize on the right temperature.

Is there something the pros do for this sort of thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best way I think is thermal compound and glue it to the device, then just buy another thermal probe :)   Short of that you can try and tape or clamp the flexible wire, I've had luck using a binder clip or some locking pliers like vice grips.  Then curve it so the bend in the wire provides natural holding force onto the heat sink.   That way what you're using to hold the probe doesn't affect the measurement.  But really glue is the way to go.

For more pro use you can use thermal loggers that use slightly cheaper thermal couples, there are some nice ones that help you measure air flow at the same time.

That said for another project I just built a little wind tunnel and started using the bent wire approach so it's up to you how accurate you need to be.

Comment: You can put a small dab of heatsink grease on the probe, then tape it to the heatsink with masking tape, or foam tape. If you have the budget, you can buy a thermal imaging camera. If the heatsink is big enough, you could use an IR temperature probe.

Comment: I've had decent success in the past with Kapton tape as well.

Comment: Yeah I've used kapton but the dmm probes always seem to pull it off at the slightest bump for me.  Maybe in just thinking of the fluke ones.

Comment: @mkeith a thermal imaging camera is quite tedious to calibrate for absolute temperature measurements. (One should **not** guess the emissivity or look it up in a table; it is not reliable. The ratio between emissivities at different wavelengths is more useful for a temperature measurement, but less straightforward to arrange.) A thermocouple does seem like the better-value proposition, and one can buy extremely fine thermocouples. I would use these with thermally conductive epoxy, since good thermal contact and low thermal mass is absolutely vital for a correct reading.

Answer (score 2):

If you must mount the thermocouple on the heatsink then consider a silpad or mica washer to stop possibly high volts getting into the meter which is USER INTERFACE now even if your volts are low you don't want the sensitive thermocouple meter to give errors Often the heatsinks are full of RF these days and there is enough coupling to make the meter give crazy readings  turning the equipment off and seeing an abrupt change to a believable temp will confirm this   Winding the thermocouple wire around a ferrite toroid has helped once or twice as has shielding the wire BUT these days we use the IR temo probe

Comment: Oooh, the IR method sounds promising. I'll dig that out and give it a try :)

Answer (score 1):

I like to use the self adhesive probes that have a flattened ribbon junction.

[image: u]

They require a bit of surface area of course. You might have to add a bit of insulation to get an really accurate reading, especially if there is forced convection.

If the heatsink is thick and grounded you can also drill a small hole (at least 3x the diameter deep, preferably 10x, and epoxy in a small bead thermocouple. This us potentially the most accurate method. When you are done just snip the T/C off flush (they're cheap).

You can also use an IR probe, paint the heatsink black to increase the emissivity and calibrate the IR reading (manually or by fiddling with the emissivity adjustment) with a thermocouple as above. This is useful if the heatsink happens to have hundreds of volts of high frequency AC on it and you can only get sensible readings with the circuit 'off'.